# addEventListener with if condition not working

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onclicklistener

I am trying to make a button that triggers the `<p>` element to be changed from Boing! to Bummtschak!

When the page loads Bummtschak! is displayed, although I did not click and nothing happens in the following click event.
I do not know what I am doing wrong.

```
const para = document.querySelector("p");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', backTo());
function backTo() {
   if (para.textContent == "Boing!") {
       para.textContent = "Bummtschak!";
   }else{
       para.textContent = "Bummtschak!";
   }
}
```

The html is:

```
...
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn"></button>
    <p>Boing!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have the `()` in the `addEventListener`

```js
const para = document.querySelector("p");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', backTo);
function backTo() {
   if (para.textContent == "Boing!") {
       para.textContent = "Bummtschak!";
   }else{
       para.textContent = "Bummtschak!";
   }
}
```

```html
   <button id="btn"></button>
    <p>Boing!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a stupid mistake!

Comment: Done, forgot to accept it, sorry. I also edited the else statement in my code to "Boing!" because otherwise it would only change once.